# howto get $('input[name=...]').val() from $('form')[...];

Tags: javascript, jquery

This my html code

```
<div id="list_refer_1">
   <form id="refer_1_0">
      <input type="hidden" name="channel" value="1">
      <input type="hidden" name="url" id="input_1_0" value="http://localhost:8000/">
      <input type="button" onclick="pullrefer(1, 0);" value=" -  "> 
      http://localhost:8000/ 
   </form>
   <form id="refer_1_xxxxx">   ///xxxxx is timestamp
      <input type="hidden" name="channel" value="1">
      <input type="hidden" name="url" id="input_1_1" value="http://127.0.0.1:8000/">
      <input type="button" onclick="pullrefer(1, 1);" value=" -  "> 
      http://127.0.0.1:8000/ 
   </form>
   <form id="refer_1_2">
      <input type="hidden" name="channel" value="1">
      <input type="hidden" name="url" id="input_1_2" value="http://localhost*">
      <input type="button" onclick="pullrefer(1, 2);" value=" -  "> 
      http://localhost* 
   </form>
   ...
```

i can get value by

```
$('#list_refer_1 #refer_1_0 input[name=url]').val();
```

but i want get

```
$('input[name=url]').val() from $('#list_refer_1 **form**')**[1]**;
```

howto get it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector (*it is zero-based*)

```
$('#list_refer_1 form:eq(1) input[name=url]').val();
```

Comment: @undefined, please do not edit posts without important reason.. (***value** An attribute value. Can be either an **unquoted single word** or a quoted string.*)